# Parse JSON field names and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've looked half a day for a solution to this, but nothing seems to work.  I want to use jQuery to load JSON from a file that essentially looks like this:

```
[{"field_a":"1","field_b":"1000","field_c":"PRINCIPAL CASH"},
{"field_a":"2","field_b":"2000","field_c":"TRUST ASSETS"},
{"field_a":"3","field_b":"3000","field_c":" BONDS"},
{"field_a":"4","field_b":"4000","field_c":" STOCKS"}]
```

What I want to do is parse the JSON to dynamically populate input fields, so something like (please note that ??field?? and ??field value?? is what I need to know):

```
<input id="field_a" name="field_a" value="">
<input id="field_b" name="field_b" value="">
<input id="field_c" name="field_c" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    //GET THE JSON DATA
    $.getJSON('../coreScripts/selectGeneralLedger.php', function(data) {

       //PARSE TO FIELDS
        $.each(data, function(index) {  
            $("#"+data[index].??field name??).attr("value",  data[index].??field value??);
        }) //END PARSE

     }); //End get JSON 

});
</script>
```

I know how to access the field values manually using data[index].field_a, but can't for the life of me figure out how to parse this dynamically.  Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE****

adeneo gave me the solution below in the comments.  Simple.  Here's the script:

```
var data = [{"field_a":"1","field_b":"1000","field_c":"PRINCIPAL CASH"}, {"field_a":"2","field_b":"2000","field_c":"TRUST ASSETS"}, {"field_a":"3","field_b":"3000","field_c":" BONDS"}, {"field_a":"4","field_b":"4000","field_c":" STOCKS"}];


$.each(data, function(index, obj) {  
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        $('<input />', {id: key, name:key, value:value}).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

Comment: With which of the objects from the array do you want to populate the input fields?

Comment: @PSL: No! jQuery has already taken care of that in `$.getJSON`.

Comment: aaah i see, but if he is getting the data then it should work. `data[index].field_a` should evaluate

Comment: lol, yes.  As I mention at the end, I know how to get the values manually, but I want to loop through the data without having to manually enter in the field names.  That way I can name inputs in my html and run the script to have them dynamically populated with the JSON data using jQuery.

Comment: ***http://jsfiddle.net/NVzjL/1/*** <- something like this ?

Comment: Let me approach this another way, if I wanted to load the JSON and simply output a list of the field names and values of every record, how would I do that via a loop?  So, say I want output to the user to look like this:

    field_a: 1
    field_b: 1000
    field_c: PRINCIPAL CASH

    field_a: 2
    field_b: 2000
    field_c: TRUST ASSETS

...and so on?  How do I access the field/column names in JSON with a parsing script?

Comment: adeneo, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Simple solution I had just overlooked.  Thanks a ton!

Sorry to everyone else if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: If you found a solution please answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: System won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours:

Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not understand you, it can be an answer.

```
 $.each(data, function(index) {  
     $.each(data[index] ,function(key,value){
            console.log("key :" + key + " value :" + value );
     })
 }) //END PARSE
```

`key` variable is the answer what you request for.